# enableBodyScroll unsuccessful - targetElement must be provided when calling enableBodyScroll on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, frontend

Выдает такую ошибку в проекте на Vue.js. Не могу найти достаточной информации в сети. Не критично, но работать неприятно в дебаге. Возможно кто-то сталкивался. Подскажите что и куда нужно вставить чтобы больше не выскакивала.
Спасибо!